# Retrieve value from dictionary from another class in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

Im trying to get the value from the following Dictionary in another Class, I tried "Getter.UserData", I keep getting "Getter.Type does not have member called UserData". How can I retrieve for example the value in UserData["username"] in another class?

Im trying to get my User details from php through Json, and to display it at the profile for the user's page. Is this the right approach?

```
class Getter{
var UserData: [String: String] = ["Username":"",
    "Profile Pic":"default.png",
    "Followers":"1",
    "Following":"2",
    "Glimps":"3"]

func ProfileDetails(){
DataManager.getJson{(Data) -> Void in
    let json = JSON(data: Data)
    self.UserData["Username"]=toString((json[0]["username"])) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code that generates the error. It looks to me like you are trying to fetch UserData from the Getter class rather than from an instance of the class, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to make UserData a [Type Property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID264)

```
static var UserData: [String: String] = [...]
```

so you can access it with

```
Getter.UserData["Username"]
```

or make an instance of the class and access its values:

```
let getter = Getter()
getter.UserData["Username"]
```